# Сравнение int[0][0] и int[0][1] используя Arrays.deepEquals. JAVA

Tags: java, массивы

Как можно сравнить `int[0][0]` и `int[0][1] ... int[0][n]`?

При использовании:

```
Arrays.deepEquals
```

получаю

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(new int[0][0],new int[0][3]));
output : true
```

При сравнение массивов типа `int[i][j]`, где `i != 0`, используя `Arrays.deepEquals` все ок. Но есть необходимость сравнивать массивы, где `i == 0`.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: не понимаю, в чем загвоздка, вызываете метод и получаете результат. Другое дело, что это не совсем логично, new int[0][3]  - это пустой массив в который нельзя ничего записать и сверять соответственно нечего.

Comment: У меня просто был метод в который я пытался передать координаты выстрела используя массив и сравнивал с координатами поля.
public void doShoot(int[][] shootPoints) {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
if (Arrays.deepEquals(new int[i][j], shootPoints)) {
if (Field.cells[i][j] == Field.Type.EMPTY || Field.cells[i][j] == Field.Type.AMBIENT_AREA) {
 Field.cells[i][j] = Field.Type.ALREADY_SHOOTED;
.....
Как я уже понял, это было абсолютно неправильно. Надо переделывать программу используя Point(x,y), например.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Есть предположение, что вы неправильно используете двумерные массивы. Вы действительно во славу перфоманса можете хранить координаты в массивах, но для 2D достаточно обычного массива из двух элементов, где сoord[0] - x, coord[1] - y.  В таком случае множество выстрелов будет представлять из себя двумерный массив (массив массивов) где arr[0][0] - x-координата 1го выстрела, arr[1][1] - y-координата второго выстрела и т.д.